# VisualStudio nuget: Unable to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Graph.Auth'

Tags: visual-studio, microsoft-graph-api, nuget-package

When attempting to install a package that has a dependency to Microsoft.Graph.Auth, the nuget package manager in VisualStudio errors with this message:

```
 Unable to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Graph.Auth'. Source(s) used: 'nuget.org'
```

No other information is provided.

I can successfully install the Microsoft package manually, however.
The package that depends on the Microsoft package has this in its .nuspec, so as far as I can tell, it should work:

```
 <dependency id="Microsoft.Graph.Auth" version="1.0.0-preview.7" />
```

Comment: Which version you are using for nuget package manger and for visual studio?

Comment: `1.0.0-preview.7` does it mean you are using a preview version? If so, have you checked the `include prerelease`? https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uin0.png

Comment: Thanks, @TinyWang, but yes, the "include prerelease" option is checked.

Comment: @vickykumar : the nuget package manager version is 5.11.2.2, and visual studio is at 16.11.20

Answer (score 0):

I can find it by checking `Include prerelease` option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As Per the [doc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Auth/#readme-body-tab) Microsoft.Graph.Auth is deprecated and no longer maintained , either you can try by suggested alternative package **Azure.Identity** or try by  installing via the NuGet package manager console.

```
NuGet\Install-Package Microsoft.Graph.Auth -Version 1.0.0-preview.7
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Deprecated doesn't mean it should fail to install. If I could easily drop the package, I would, but it's not possible at present; it's on the schedule to do when time permits.

Comment: I'll also note that installing via the nuget package manager console works perfectly using this command: `Install-Package packageName -Version 0.0.0.1 -IncludePrerelease`

Comment: Thanks for the update , this is also mentioned in the doc itself ,i will update my answer , it will helps others as well.